# How to calculate rolling correlation coefficient in a groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a DataFrame how would one calculate the rolling correlation coefficient of a particular column for N periods(5), while in a groupby?

My Attempts, I feel like i'm close, but missing something simple..

Using Corr

```
df['cor'] = df.groupby('DIMENSION').val1.apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=5).corr())
```

Using Another Stack Overflow Suggestion

```
df['cor'] = df.groupby('DIMENSION').val1.apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=5).corr()[df'val1']df['index'])
```

Trying corrwith defaults

```
df['cor'] = df.groupby('DIEMNSION').val1.apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=5).corrwith())
```

DataFrame:

```
Dimension,Val1,Index
A,15677,0
A,19191,1
A,19961,2
A,10004,3
A,17899,4
A,10933,5
A,12953,6
A,19431,7
A,17637,8
A,13310,9
A,10113,10
A,19108,11
A,17169,12
A,13859,13
A,11466,14
A,13673,15
A,15049,16
B,14996,17
B,17679,18
B,12944,19
C,19927,20
C,10659,21
C,14561,22
C,18842,23
C,13784,24
C,14562,25
C,10145,26
```

Comment: What are you correlating with?

Comment: The index, I just need the R-Squared of the data over and evenly spaced set of time. Its the accuracy of the linear regression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
def mytrans(x):
    return pd.DataFrame(x['Val1'].rolling(window=5).corr(x['Index']))

df['corr'] = df.groupby('Dimension')[['Val1','Index']].apply(mytrans)

df
```

Comment: This is perfect!